# rails delete controller with ActiveRecord not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am using Rails and have a controller for Bills in which there is a destroy method. In the browser, when I use the delete url e.g. localhost/delete/2 (2 in this case is the ID of the relevant bill), the bill never gets deleted.  Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong (or if I should additional configs here).  The routes is copied below ass well.

**bills_controller**

```
  def destroy
    @bill = Bill.find(params[:id])
    @bill.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Bill was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

**Routes**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :bills
  get 'bills/index'
end
```

Should I be adding a specific route for the delete action in the routes.rb file?
I have the following on my HTML page:

```
  <td><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/bills/1">Destroy</a></td>
```

**delete & index portion of the controller**:

```
 def index
    @bills = Bill.all
  end

  # DELETE /bills/1
  # DELETE /bills/1.json
  def destroy
    @bill = Bill.find(params[:id])
    @bill.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to bills_url, notice: 'Bill was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

**index erb file**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Bills</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Body</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @bills.each do |bill| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= bill.title %></td>
        <td><%= bill.body %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', bill %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_bill_path(bill) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
```

Comment: routing to `destroy` requires the request be made by the HTTP `DELETE` method. Just visiting this route in the browser will create a `GET` request and will probably raise a no route matches error. Most browsers do not support true `DELETE` requests so rails falsifies this for you by adding a `_method` param and then handles the request appropriately in it's internals. As a side note you did not post your `bills` routes but rather `posts`

Comment: thank you for pointing it out - what do I need to change to ensure that the delete gets called?

Comment: you have `link_to 'Destroy', post` this seems to be an on going issue are you sure you are posting the actual source?

Answer (score 1):

Your browser will use an HTTP action of GET.  You need it to be DELETE.  You can install a plugin for your browser that will let you make rest calls, and set the action, but I think it's easier to user curl:

`curl -X DELETE localhost/bills/2`

You might need to adjust the hostname in the URL, but you get the idea.

Comment: I have a link in the URL for delete (  <td><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/bills/1">Destroy</a></td>)

Comment: Yes, that should work.  But just visiting that URL with the browser will not.

Comment: But you won't want to hard-code the href.  Use a path helper, and pass the object to be deleted.

Comment: Like this:  `<%= link_to "Delete", bill_path(@bill), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }%>`

Comment: In the view.  Probably `app/views/bills/show.html.erb`

Comment: I already have this in my index file: <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', bill, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>.  I guess I need to change bill_path part

Comment: And does that work?  Note the only difference between ours is the second argument to `link_to`.  You've got `bill`, I've got `bill_path(bill)`.

Comment: the bill_path change leads to  "ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Bills#index" exceotion -previouly the tmeplate was being rendered.

Comment: What happens when you click the link there (without bill_path)?

Comment: it shows me the info for the bill but does not delete the data

Comment: Please post the controller code the the index action, and maybe the whole index view file.

Comment: Please post the controller code the the index action

Comment: Oh, wait, I see it.  In your view, in your destroy link, you are passing `post`, not `bill`.

Comment: that's  a typo - please ignore

Comment: And I still think it should be `bill_path(bill)`.  What's the exact error message or incorrect behavior you are seeing, anyway?

Comment: exception. it does not show the url. "ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Bills#index" exceotion -previouly the tmeplate was being rendered

Comment: You are mixing and matching `bill` and `post`.

Comment: I meant what was the error or behaviour without `bill_path(bill)`

Comment: shows the url, hitting delete for the Bil takes me to the url where it shows me the details for the bill

Comment: I think I will create the project again - I initially may have created without js support

Comment: @Daiku by the way link_to can infer the singular path `bill_path` if just the object is passed. Just some of that fun rails automagic

Comment: Yeah, Rails is awesome that way!

Answer (score 1):

Issue was that my rails app vendor javascript directory was empty and not pulling in the javascript files required to enable the delete call.